# How to have a multi-line return for a function in Rails / Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The following **only renders the last** partial line:

```
def default_sidebars
  render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box1'
  render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box2'
  render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box3'
  render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box4'
end
```

**How could I get it to render all lines?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def default_sidebars
  res = render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box1'
  res += render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box2'
  res += render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box3'
  res += render :partial => 'shared/sidebars/box4'
end
```